# How do I start Dynamic PGO with Docker in NET6?

Tags: docker, .net-6.0, pgo

As some documents to enable PGO:

```
export DOTNET_ReadyToRun=0
export DOTNET_TieredPGO=1
export DOTNET_TC_QuickJitForLoops=1
```

But I didn't find how to config in dockerfile, or where should I config in build or publish stage.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be normal environemnt variables as per documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

```
ENV DOTNET_ReadyToRun=0
ENV DOTNET_TieredPGO=1
ENV DOTNET_TC_QuickJitForLoops=1
```